# Parsing ODataQueryOptions<type> without EF/Nhibernate

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, odata

I have a project with a large codebase that uses an in-house data access layer to work with the database. However, we want to support OData access to the system. I'm quite comfortable with expression trees in C#. How do I get at something I can parse here in order to get the structure of their actual query?

Is there a way to get an AST out of this thing that I can turn into sql code?

Comment: What is the underlying database technology? There may already be a query provider for it, especially if its query language is SQL.

Comment: Classic ADO.net over sql server with a thin wrapper layer generated with T4 Templates. There is no LINQ provider, as all calls go through stored procedures. There are a lot of issues with synonyms, heirarchyids, and attempting to work with table-valued parameters that made EF a no-go when we started. Don't really care to bring it in now if I can avoid it.

Comment: On the plus side, I won't need projections/grouping. Just plain filtering, paging, and sorting.

Answer (score 2):

Essentially, you need to implement you own [Query Provider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb546158(v=vs.110).aspx) which known how to translate the expression tree to an underlying query.

A simplified version of a controller method would be:

```
    [ODataRoute("foo")]
    public List<Foo> GetFoo(ODataQueryOptions<Foo> queryOptions)
    {
        var queryAllFoo = _myQueryProvider.QueryAll<Foo>();
        var modifiedQuery = queryOptions.ApplyTo(queryAllFoo);
        return modifiedQuery.ToList();
    }
```

However!

1. This is not trivial, it took me about 1 month to implement custom OData query processing
2. You need to build the EDM model, so the WebApi OData can process and build right expression trees
3. It might involve reflection, creation of types at runtime in a dynamic assembly (for the projection), compiling lambda expressions for the best performance
4. WebAPI OData component has some limitations, so if you want to get relations working, you need to spend much more extra time, so in our case we did some custom query string transformation (before processing) and injecting joins into expression trees when needed
5. There are too many details to explain in one answer, it's a long way..

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`ODataQueryOptions<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn747121(v=vs.118).aspx) to get abstract syntax trees for the `$filter` and `$orderby` query options. (`$skip` and `$top` are also available as parsed integers.) Since you don't need/want LINQ support, you could then simply pass the ASTs to a repository method, which would then visit the ASTs to build up the appropriate SQL stored proc invocation. You will not call `ODataQueryOptions.ApplyTo`. Here's a sketch:

```
public IEnumerable<Thing> Get(ODataQueryOptions<Thing> opts)
{
    var filter = opts.Filter.FilterClause.Expression;
    var ordering = opts.OrderBy.OrderByClause.Expression;
    var skip = opts.Skip.Value;
    var top = opts.Top.Value;

    return this.Repository.GetThings(key, filter, ordering, skip, top);
}
```

Note that `filter` and `ordering` in the above are instances of [`Microsoft.OData.Core.UriParser.Semantic.SingleValueNode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.odata.core.uriparser.semantic.singlevaluenode(v=vs.113).aspx). That class has a convenient `Accept<T>` method, but you probably do not want your repository to depend on that class directly. That is, you should probably use a helper to produce an intermediate form that is independent of Microsoft's OData implementation.

If this is a common pattern, consider using [parameter binding](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api) so you can get the various query options directly from the controller method's parameter list.